# Select tuples between two different dates in SQL Lite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to find all the results between two dates in SQLite.

```
select log_ID
from Message
where Timestamp between DATE('2014-04-17 03:27:08','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
                    and DATE('2014-04-18 03:27:08','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```

This query is executing successfully but it gives no results.

I've tried using DATE and TO_DATE functions as well.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Message(
    Log_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Session_ID TEXT NOT NULL,
    Timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Admill_Msg TEXT, Logcat_Msg TEXT);
```

Sample tuples:

```
155|admil.out.txt|2014-04-17 03:26:48.730000||PID:926 TID:926 TAG:I/Zygote LOG:Preloading resources...
156|admil.out.txt|2014-04-17 03:26:48.730000||PID:926 TID:926 TAG:W/Resources LOG:Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080096 (android:drawable/toast_frame) that varies with configuration!!
157|admil.out.txt|2014-04-17 03:26:48.740000||PID:926 TID:926 TAG:W/Resources LOG:Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080105 (android:drawable/btn_check_on_pressed_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
```

Comment: Wrong implementation of Between call

Answer (score 2):

You are using the [date function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) wrong; there is not format parameter.
`strftime` could do such formatting, but that is not necessary because the timestamps are simply strings.

Just compare the strings directly:

```
select log_ID
from Message
where Timestamp between '2014-04-17 03:27:08'
                    and '2014-04-18 03:27:08';
```